# <p-multiSelect> accessible without header

Tags: accessibility, primeng, multi-select

my p-multiSelect element is working and is also accessible. But I don't want the search Header Option so I did:

[showHeader]= false;

which is also working but now the p-multiSelect element is not accessible anymore as I can't reach it with the keyboard anymore.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Can you be more precise please? By “Reach it” you mean setting focus on it by means of the _Tab_ key? So it’s not in the tab order any more? Ideally, could you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by adding a code snippet?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue with focus. I inspected the [p-multiSelect](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/multiselect) and have doubts about its accessibility in its default configuration: It doesn’t respect the [Combobox Pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/combobox/). `combobox` role is missing, `listbox` is on the wrong element, `aria-selected` and the role are missing for options. _Enter_ and _arrow down_ don’t open the listbox, and focus is lost when closing it with _Esc_. Some keyboard users might manage to work around these issues.